# Python reading first four lines from readlines()

Tags: python

How can I read the first four lines from `readlines()`, I am getting a `STDIN` from proxy to my script:

```
GET http://www.yum.com/ HTTP/1.1
Host: www.yum.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
```

i read it using `sys.stdin.readlines()` and log it to file, but i want to log only `GET` and `User-Agent` lines to the file.

```
while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readlines()
    for l in line:
        log = open('/tmp/redirect.log', 'a')
        log.write(l)
        log.close()
```

Comment: Use 4 spaces per indentation level.

Comment: Why are you opening, writing and closing the file for every individual line that gets read?  That seems silly.

Comment: i am just testing the output so checking it by logging to a file..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `with` ensures good closure of the log.
You can iterate through `sys.stdin` as with any file-type object in Python, which is faster as it doesn't need to create a list.

```
with open('/tmp/redirect.log', 'a') as log:
    while True: #If you need to continuously check for more.
        for line in sys.stdin:
            if line.startswith(("GET", "User-Agent")):
                log.write(line)
```

The following is an efficient method as it doesn't check for the same lines again and again, and only checks while there are lines it needs left. Probably not needed given the situation, but if you had more items to check for, and more things to sort through, could be worth doing. It also means you keep track of the parts you have, and don't read beyond the lines you need. This could be valuable if reading is an expensive operation.

```
with open('/tmp/redirect.log', 'a') as log:
    while True: #If you need to continuously check for more.
        needed = {"GET", "User-Agent"}
        for line in sys.stdin:
            for item in needed:
                if line.startswith(item):
                    log.write(line)
                    break
            needed.remove(item)
            if not needed: #The set is empty, we have found all the lines we need.
                break
```

The set is unordered, but we can assume the lines will come in order, and hence get logged in order.

This kind of set-up may also be needed for more complex checking of lines (e.g: with regular expressions). In your case however, the first example is concise and should work well.

Comment: hi lattyware, this is a good solution....but i have another function which does operation on that line and looks like its not breaking the loop properly

Comment: @Lattyware Nice to know that `startswith` also accepts a tuple of strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can check the contents of the line before writing to logs:

```
while True:
    lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith('GET') or line.startswith('User-Agent:'):
            log = open('/tmp/redirect.log', 'a')
            log.write(l)
            log.close()
```

For more complex checks, you could also use a regular expression.

Comment: gives me this error:    if line.startswith('GET'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Comment: @krisdigitx That was because of a problem with variable names. I've updated my answer with better names.

Comment: thanks jcollado...i have used part of your solution too...cheers

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your input **always** start with the 4 lines you want to get, this should work:

```
log = open('/tmp/redirect.log', 'a') 
for l in sys.stdin.readlines()[:4]:
    log.write(l)
log.close()
```

Otherwise you need to parse the input and possibly use regex (there's another answer on that).

Comment: Why open and close the log for each line that's appended?

Comment: I just copied his code, the answer is readlines()[:4] - I agree that's not needed at all, though. Editing.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> lines
0: ['GET http://www.yum.com/ HTTP/1.1',
'Host: www.yum.com',
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:9.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0.1',
'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language: en-gb,en;q=0.5',
'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7',
'Proxy-Connection: keep-alive']
>>> patterns = ["GET", "User-Agent"]
>>> for line in lines:
...     for pattern in patterns:
...         if line.startswith(pattern):
...             with open("/tmp/redirect.log", "a") as f:
...                 f.write(line)
                break
```

`with` should be used inside if statement, if lines list is long, this will lead to opening of the file handler for long time. `break` is used becasue every line will match only one pattern , if a line has already matched a pattern, there is no need to check for other patterns in the list.